# Pregunta: ¿Por qué no se ejecuta el programa en consola?

Tags: java, eclipse

Escribí un programa en Eclipse y cuando lo ejecuto el programa no sucede nada en la consola.

```
package vari;

public class variable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int edad=15;
        System.out.println(edad);
    }

}
```

Comment: el código va como texto y no como imagen

Comment: gracias por la aclaratoria

Comment: no puedo volver a preguntar, podrias responderme la pregunta?

Comment: para empezar corrige el punto que te menciono y *edita* tu pregunta haciendo las correcciones mencionadas, para que puedas recibir ayuda y evites los puntos negativos

Comment: Hola, date una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour  para formular mejor las preguntas y obtener respuestas. En Java se debe respetar el estilo de escritura CamelCase  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase Escribir el nombre de la clase en mayúsculas.

Comment: Para que funcione tendrías que indicar en `Eclipse` que `variable` es tu clase principal (`main`). Cuando pruebes el proyecto entonces se ejecutará el código. De todos modos, lee sobre convención de nombres en Java y da nombres coherentes a tus clases. La clase que contiene el método `main` generalmente se llaman `Main` o `Principal` o algo así.

Comment: Tienes la pestaña de consola abiera o disponible? Por favor adjunta una captura de pantalla de lo que te sucede...